# Generating Dynamic Navbar based on SQL results?

Tags: php, html, sql

Hello superiors coders.

Im trying to make a shop section as part of a website which includes a sidebar navbar which can be clicked to specify sections of a product e.g. electrical or cctv. I've already done this by allocating products a category and then to generate the navbar i am querying all the categories and then looping through creating the HTML so the bar displays all the categories

Example

```
<div class="leftside" id="leftbar">
<nav class="menu-top">
    <ul class="off-canvas-list" style="font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold">
        <li style="padding-top: 2.7rem"></li>
        <?php foreach ($item_list as $list) {
            echo "<li><a href='/welcome/shop_search/" . $list->type . "'>" . $list->type . "</a></li>";
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is i want to be able to use sub categories but i have not got a clue as to how the SQL data should be set out as well as how to incorporate the intelligence to loop through add the main categories like so and then add dropdown sub categories.

```
+------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+
| ID         | Name           | Main | Sub | Parent  |
+------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+
| 1          | Cabling        |  1   | 0   |         | 
| 2          | network cable  |  0   | 1   | cabling | 
| 2          | electric cable |  0   | 1   | cabling | 
+------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+
```

this is how I've set up my SQL and I'm aiming to put some sort of logical if statement some how binding the sub categories to the main category so when the loop has finished its creates the navbar with the mains being the buttons and the sub categories in a collapsable inside the relevant main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make another select in each iteration:

```
<div class="leftside" id="leftbar">
<nav class="menu-top">
<ul class="off-canvas-list" style="font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold">
    <li style="padding-top: 2.7rem"></li>
    <?php foreach ($item_list as $list) {
        echo "<li><a href='/welcome/shop_search/" . $list->type . "'>" . $list->type . "</a></li>";


        //select * from types where sub=list->type
        //$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($select)
        if($num_rows>0){
            echo '<ul>';
                //for each
                //sub
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

For the design I recomend you the [bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: Can you see this being any problem in a MVC structure? i am using code academy

Comment: There is no any problem, if you not want do the select in the view you can save the sub items in the same main array (multidimensional), but you have to write both loops in the controller previously.

Comment: thanks for the help i ended up using your idea but with a helper instead to keep it cleaner ;-)